# why getName() returns null using mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Person.java is this code.

```
public class Person {
private String name;

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

and this is the test code.

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import junit.framework.*;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.Spy;


public class PersonTest {

@Mock
private Person person;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testSetName() {
    person.setName("Larry");
    assertEquals("Larry", person.getName());        
}
```

I test with this code, but person.getName() returns null and my test fails.

I've no idea why this fails.
Can you explain why? :(

Comment: You never initialize your `person`.

Comment: @AnubianNoob: Mockito does that for you.

Comment: Thought so, just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking `Person`; if you don't explicitly tell Mockito to return something for a method it will return `null`.

Note that what you are doing doesn't make much sense. You appear to want to test `Person`, then you should not mock `Person` but create a real instance of `Person` using `new Person()`. You use mocking to replace (complex) dependencies of a class you want to test, so you can tests its behavior on specific inputs. That is not what you want here.

Instead do:

```
@Test
public void testSetName() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Larry");
    assertEquals("Larry", person.getName()); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you're not testing your code. You're testing Mockito.

The person should NOT be mocked. Mocking a class means: replace the implementation of all the methods by methods doing nothing. So that's what happens: `getName()` is replaced by a method that does nothing. So it returns null.

So the test should be:

```
public class PersonTest {

    private Person person;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        person = new Person();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetName() {
        person.setName("Larry");
        assertEquals("Larry", person.getName());        
    }
}
```

Mocking is useful to mock **dependencies** of the object under test. So if you test a UserService, and this UserService uses a UserDAO, you can mock the UserDAO to test the real code of UserService: you tell the DAO to return 2 users when its `findAll()` method is called, then you call a method of UserService that internally calls `userDao.findAll()`, and the userService receives two users. And you can then also verify that `userDao.findAll()` has been called.

Comment: So what should he do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically test should be like

```
@Test
public void testSetName() {
    when(person.getName()).thenReturn("Larry");
    assertEquals("Larry", person.getName());        
}
```

but it's useless really as it will always pass. There is no user defined logic really here to test. As someone said above you are testing mockito rather than your method.